# Error:Could not download ecj.jar (org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:4.4): No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

Hello Friends i am new on android studio and after installation i found an issue gradle build failed because

Error:Could not download ecj.jar (org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:4.4): No cached version available for offline mode

Comment: i have the same problem by "gradlew assembleRelease"
it can be a SSL mismatch
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!

http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.4/ecj-4.4.jar

works with http instead https

Comment: and the problem disappeared after some time (minutes) :-D

Comment: i m facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **File** and Click on **Settings** or **Other Settings**
2. Select **Build, Execution, Deployment**
3. On **Build Tools** , choose **Gradle** and uncheck **Offline work**

You can now synchronize Gradle and run the build